# Ample divisor on blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X/k$ be a smooth variety over a number field $k$ and $Y/k$ a smooth subvariety of codimension $r \geq 2$. Let $\pi: \tilde{X} \to X$ be the blowup of $X$ along $Y$, with $\tilde{Y} : = \pi^{-1}Y$. I've read somewhere before that

> If $A$ is an ample divisor on $X$, then there exists an integer $N$ such that $-\tilde{Y}+N\pi^*A$ is an ample divisor on $\tilde{X}$ by the Nakai-Moishezon criterion.

Why is this true? I've referred to Hartshorne but the result is for surfaces, and I don't see any way the criterion is connected to the result above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is proposition II.7.10 in Hartshorne, together with the fact that $\mathcal O_{\pi}(1) \cong \mathcal O(-\tilde Y)$.